# variable declared and not used

Tags: for-loop, go

I am trying to learn Go, but when trying out a simple for loop, I found it difficult to get it working. This code does not compile if I define the variable a in the main function, it gives an error 'a declared but not used'. I don't understand when a variable must be declared and when it must not be. Thanks.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {   


    for a:=0;a<4;a++ {      
        fmt.Printf("value of a is %d\n",a)
}
```

Comment: The code is missing a closing brace `}` at the end. Adding it works as intended.

Comment: OK , sorry, copied it wrong. But what about declaring varibles, when  should variables be declared and when shouldn't they be?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options available

1. Declare the variable explicitly and then use

   ```
   var a int
   a = 0
   ```
2. Declare and assign in one statement without having to specify the type (it is inferred)

   ```
   a:=0
   ```

Note the difference in `=` and `:=`. If you use `:=` twice, it counts as a redeclaration. In other words, `=` is for assignment only, whereas `:=` is for declaration and assignment in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, you have the 'not used error', is because the expression `a:=0` declares a new variable with the same name in the scope of the loop. If you already have the variable 'a' declared before the loop, change it to `for a=0; a<4; a++` (without the colon).